# How do I confirm whether a particular Apache configuration directive is set?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, keepalive, keep-alive

How do I dynamically check/list a particular Apache configuration directive?  I know that this can be checked manually from `httpd.conf` file, but is there any other way this can be confirmed/found from a *running* Apache server process?

For example: In my case, I was checking for `KeepAlive` configuration directive.  I even checked with the command `/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -h`, but I don't find it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like the apache binary itself will provide this info - from [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html):

> -S
>
> Show the settings as parsed from the config file (currently only shows
>   the virtualhost settings).

There exist options to show modules loaded and compile-time flags used, but the above is the only option related to config settings.  It seems even the CGI environment available, as well as info returned by [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) does not contain the type of details you're looking for.

**However**, all is not lost - if you're prepared to enable/install the apache module [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html), you'll find it answers that and many more questions regarding apache configuration.

Example output from the "Server Settings" page of the localhost/server-info location:

> Server Version: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)
>   PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny4 with Suhosin-Patch
>   mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
>   mod_wsgi/2.5
>             Python/2.5.2
>
> Server Built: Nov 14 2009 20:23:49 
>   Module Magic Number: 20051115:15
>   Hostname/port: localhost:80
>   Timeouts: connection: 300
>   **keep-alive: 300**    MPM Name: Prefork
>   MPM Information: Max Daemons: 150
>   Threaded: no Forked: yes    Server
>   Architecture: 32-bit    Server Root:
>   /etc/apache2    Config File:
>   /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Note the *keep-alive* highlighted - if your intention is to script the check (although this could also be done against the config file itself), I think calling `lynx --dump localhost/server-info` could well assist in your endeavour (after a quick call to `a2enmod info` and an apache restart).

HTH, and YMMV. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I tried to enable Apache module `mod_info` by following the instructions given here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html, but when I invoke `http://myserver/server-info`, it fails with `HTTP 404 Not Found`.  Of course, I restarted Apache service also.  How do I enable/configure this Apache module?

Comment: Depends which distro you're running and what package management system it is using, really.  But first off confirm that the mod_info module is actually loading/loaded into the apache binary, either dynamically or statically.  Try the `-M` and `-l` flags to the apache binary directly, and see if `mod_info` or `info_module` shows up...